# Incorrect usage of pointers resulting in wrong output?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct that is filled in completly. The name is strdup'd. What I want to do is, create a pointer array where the element in the array points to that strdup's variable.

This is what I have tried:

```
struct Student{
        char *name;
        int age;
}Student;

void storeAdrress(const Student *student1,char **arrayOfPointers){
    arrayOfPointers[0] = student1->name;    

    printf("Struct variable: %p",student1->name);
    printf("Pointer variable: %p",arrayOfPointers[0]);
}

int main(void){
    Student *student1 = calloc(1,sizeof(Student));
    student1->name = strdup("Tom");

    char *arrayOfPointers[100] = {0};

    storeAdrress(student1,arrayOfPointers);

    free(student1->name);
    free(student1);

    return(0);
}
```

This is my output:

```
Struct variable: (0x5502a80)
Pointer variable: (nil)
```

My aim is to get `arrayOfPointers[0]` to have the address of the name. This is clearly not working because `arrayOfPointers[0]` is not storing the pointer location.

Could someone how me what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: `sizeof(Student*)` is the size of the pointer. `sizeof(Student)` is the size of the struct, `sizeof(*student1)` is the size of the struct. So `calloc(1,sizeof(Student*));` allocates only enough memory for one pointer.

Comment: @WeatherVane I made the change, and am still gettting the same issue.

Comment: This isn't even C. `const Student * student1` should be `const struct Student * student1`, for instance.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths the struct is printing as expected with the code I have. I also tried it with the your change, there was no no diffrence.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I wondered, since my MSVC code won't compile without the `struct` keyword in there, if OP's compiler was more lenient. There is no `typedef`.

Comment: That's because you created a global instance of Student. The way you are using it, your declaration should be `typedef struct Student{ ...`.

Comment: @Brandon having added `typedef` before `struct Student` and corrected the `calloc` statement, this program prints the two addresses as the same value.

Comment: @WeatherVane maybe I am misunderstanding. Are you saying I should change, 'void storeAdrress(const Student *student1,char **arrayOfPointers){' to 'void storeAdrress(typedef struct Student *student1,char **arrayOfPointers){'

Comment: @Brandon posting an answer was easier than trying to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weather Vane beat me to it, but here's an additional correction of your code without using `typedef`, and adding some error checking:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Student{
    char *name;
    int age;
};

void storeAddress(struct Student * stdt, char ** pArray, size_t index)
{
    pArray[index] = stdt->name;    
    printf("Struct variable: %p\n", (void *) stdt->name);
    printf("Pointer variable: %p\n", (void *) pArray[index]);
}

int main(void)
{
    struct Student *student1 = calloc(1,sizeof(*student1));
    if ( !student1 ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory for struct Student");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    student1->name = strdup("Tom");
    if ( !student1->name ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory for student name");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *arrayOfPointers[100] = {0};

    storeAddress(student1, arrayOfPointers, 0);

    free(student1->name);
    free(student1);

    return 0;
}
```

with output:

```
Paul@Pauls-iMac:~/Documents/src/sandbox/names$ ./names
Struct variable: 0x7fd632403210
Pointer variable: 0x7fd632403210
Paul@Pauls-iMac:~/Documents/src/sandbox/names$
```

Comment: I missed the `(void*)` cast essential for the `%p` format (and the error checking) so +1.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths Thank you for the answer. Any idea why my question got downvoted?

Comment: @Brandon: It wasn't me, but questions often get downvoted when the underlying issue is really just a fundamental misapplication of C, which unfortunately is basically the case here. Personally, since the question clearly explained the issue, contained your full code, the expected output, and the actual output, such that it was easy to diagnose and solve the problem, I thought it was a pretty decent question.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Ohh ok thank for the info. My account just got a flag because of the down votes, and I tried my best to follow the guidelines when asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tinkering with your program. I added `typedef` to the struct definition, I corrected the use of `calloc` to specify the `struct` size, instead of a pointer size, and I added a couple of `newline`s. It prints the same value for both addresses.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Student{
    char *name;
    int age;
} Student;

void storeAdrress(const Student *student1,char **arrayOfPointers){
    arrayOfPointers[0] = student1->name;    
    printf("Struct variable: %p\n", student1->name);
    printf("Pointer variable: %p\n", arrayOfPointers[0]);
}

int main(void){
    char *arrayOfPointers[100] = {0};
    Student *student1 = calloc(1, sizeof(*student1));
    student1->name = strdup("Tom");
    storeAdrress(student1, arrayOfPointers);

    free(student1->name);
    free(student1);

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Struct variable: 00762DE0
Pointer variable: 00762DE0
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Any idea why my question got downvoted?

Comment: @Brandon it wasn't me, but perhaps because that wasn't the code that gave the output quoted.

Comment: Ohh ok thank for the info. My account just got a flag because of the down votes, and I tried my best to follow the guidelines when asking.